# (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list') calculating the average score in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the average score. but there seems to be some problem with my code. I'm not sure what to do but it says in the introduction:
f) Create a new list called avg_scores that is the list of average extra credit test scores of Marla, Ashford, and Sam.
•   Use the data from the updated all_scores to calculate the averages. You do NOT need nested for loops for this step.
•   Use a single for loop to access each inner list, then calculate the average of the inner list. Append that average to the avg_scores list.
•   Display avg_scores.

```
# a
m_list = []
print("Please enter Marla's scores one by one.")
for i in range(3):
    m_test = int(input("Enter a score: "))
    m_list.append(m_test)
print("Marla's scores: ", m_list)

# b
a_list = []
print("Please enter Ashford's scores one by one.")
for i in range(3):
    a_test = int(input("Enter a score: "))
    a_list.append(a_test)
print("Ashford's scores: ", a_list)

# c
s_list = []
print("Please enter Sam's scores one by one.")
for i in range(3):
    s_test = int(input("Enter a score: "))
    s_list.append(s_test)
print("Sam's scores: ", s_list)

# d
all_scores = []
for i in (m_list, a_list, s_list):
    all_scores.append(i)
print("All scores: ", all_scores)

# e
for i in range(len(all_scores)):
    for p in range(len(all_scores[i])):
        all_scores[i][p] = all_scores[i][p] + 2
print("All scores after extra point:", all_scores)

# f
sum_scores = sum(all_scores)
len_scores = len(all_scores)
avg_scores = sum_scores/len_scores
print("Average scores: ", avg_scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

`all_scores` is a 2-D list, so you need to take each list and add its sum to `sum_scores` using a `for` loop:

```py
avg_scores = []
for scores in all_scores:
    avg_scores.append(sum(scores) / len(scores))
```

Alternatively, if you want something more concise, you can do:

```py
avg_scores = list(score / 3 for score in map(sum, all_scores))
```

(I've only included this approach for completeness; most developers would not reasonably expect someone just starting out to be familiar with this syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

To compute the average for each student, you need to take `sum(scores) / len(scores)` for each `scores` list in `all_scores`, i.e.:

```
avg_scores = [sum(scores) / len(scores) for scores in all_scores]
```

Note that you can take advantage of `for` loops to get the scores for each student without having to copy and paste the same code for each one individually:

```
all_scores = []
for name in ("Marla", "Ashford", "Sam"):
    print(f"Please enter {name}'s scores one by one.")
    all_scores.append([int(input("Enter a score: "))for _ in range(3)])

print("All scores:", all_scores)

all_scores = [[i + 2 for i in scores] for scores in all_scores]
print("All scores after extra point:", all_scores)

avg_scores = [sum(scores) / len(scores) for scores in all_scores]
print("Average scores:", avg_scores)
```

```
Please enter Marla's scores one by one.
Enter a score: 5
Enter a score: 5
Enter a score: 4
Please enter Ashford's scores one by one.
Enter a score: 3
Enter a score: 5
Enter a score: 4
Please enter Sam's scores one by one.
Enter a score: 5
Enter a score: 5
Enter a score: 5
All scores: [[5, 5, 4], [3, 5, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
All scores after extra point: [[7, 7, 6], [5, 7, 6], [7, 7, 7]]
Average scores: [6.666666666666667, 6, 7]
```